# How to position background image in Sprite Kit? Did something change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6

[image] I tried to add a background image 1242 × 2208 but when I run it in simulator I see that picture does not cover the whole View. I know I was able to do this in previous xcode with this code:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
[self addChild:sprite];
```

Can someone tell me what I' m missing here. Thanks

this doesn't work either:

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                              CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

Comment: check the scene's scaleMode property, it's probably set to aspect fit

Comment: nope scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

Comment: Set `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFit;` Also, try `sprite.position = CGPointZero;` and `sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;`

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I tried everything you suggested  but it didn't work. I added an screenshot  to so you can see what the issue is. If you open xcode -game -sprite kit - objective c and add  an image 1242 × 2208 run it and you will see what I m struggling with.

Comment: Sorry, the scale mode should be resize fill not fit: `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;` This should fix the issue. BTW, the size of the iPhone 6's view is only 375 x 667, so only a portion of your image will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that the sprite's anchor point is not correct. This would explain why it doesn't cover the entire view.

Comment: I didn't have to put anchorpoint in xcode 5  to position it properly but when I added anchorpoint it mess it up.  It goes off the screen or if i change ScaleMode I can see half of the image.